# How to prevent first CellWidget from collapsing when adding rows to QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I'm using this simple code to try to understand why the size of the widget in the first row is changing while adding rows to the table but all other rows remain intact...

This is the simple code I'm trying:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QLabel>
#include <QCheckBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStringList HorizontalHeaders;
    HorizontalHeaders << "Number" << "Test";

    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(HorizontalHeaders);
    ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);
    ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int arg1)
{
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(arg1);
    ui->tableWidget->clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < arg1; i++){
        QWidget* thiswidget = new QWidget();
        QHBoxLayout* thislayout = new QHBoxLayout(thiswidget);
        QCheckBox* thischeckbox = new QCheckBox();
        QLabel* thislabel = new QLabel(QString::number(i));
        thislayout->addWidget(thischeckbox);
        thislayout->addWidget(thislabel);
        ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, 0, thiswidget);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Test " + QString::number(i)));
        ui->tableWidget->setRowHeight(i, thiswidget->height());
    }
}
```

the result with just 2 rows:

[image]

the result with many row:

[image]

Comment: try change to `ui->tableWidget->setRowHeight(i, thiswidget->sizeHint().height());`

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc it worked pretty well